How to keep few columns same and transpose rest columns data to rows in Google Sheets?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZlLGFdv6o3zK-K3v5ZFk3FKeuHFpgeWgltXtQf1bjdg/edit?usp=sharing
Refer to this sheet, I have a complex set of data with 333 rows, each row has year, make , model and each row also has product slugs which may vary in numbers, I want the year, make, model to be as it is and instead of products in columns, need in rows, that means instead of this:



Year
Make
Model
Slug1
Slug2
Slug3




2002
Series 1
f82
a
b
c


2003
Series 2
f83
a
b
c



We will have



Year
Make
Model
Slug




2002
Series 1
f82
a


2002
Series 1
f82
b


2002
Series 1
f82
c


2003
Series 2
f83
a


2003
Series 2
f83
b


2003
Series 2
f83
c



Please help
Tried transposing, tries with arrays but is actually a bit too complex for me

Is the no. of duplications based on the no. of products?


You may try this in a separate new tab:
=reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(index(match(,0/('New prods - Sheet1.csv'!A2:A<>"")))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Λ,index(indirect("'New prods - Sheet1.csv'!D2:"&rows('New prods - Sheet1.csv'!A:A)),c),Σ,filter(Λ,Λ<>""),
 hstack(chooserows(index('New prods - Sheet1.csv'!A2:C,c),sequence(counta(Σ),1,1,0)),tocol(Σ,1))))))


